# Fail to run nodes across machines [corda]

Tags: open-source, blockchain, corda

I am trying to run CORDA blockchain network across machines by using java version source code (source code: https://github.com/corda/samples/cordapp-example), but fail to connect nodes in a single network.

If somebody can advise any missing steps or ways to check the connection fail, it will be very thankful. Thanks!

I follow instructions of https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-cordapp.html#running-nodes-across-machines for the network setup and form network as below:

- Machine 1: Notary, PartyA, runnodes, runnodes.bat , runnodes.jar
- Machine 2: PartyB, runnodes, runnodes.bat , runnodes.jar
- Network Boostrapper Tool: https://www.corda.net/develop/resources.html

Notary_node.conf

```
devMode=true
myLegalName="O=Notary,L=London,C=GB"
notary {
    validating=false
}
p2pAddress="IP_address_of_machineA:10000"
rpcSettings {
    address="localhost:10001"
    adminAddress="localhost:10002"
}
```

PartyA_node.conf

```
devMode=true
myLegalName="O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
p2pAddress="IP_address_of_machineA:10004"
rpcSettings {
    address="localhost:10005"
    adminAddress="localhost:10006"
}
security {
    authService {
        dataSource {
            type=INMEMORY
            users=[
                {
                    password=test
                    permissions=[
                        ALL
                    ]
                    user=user1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

PartyB_node.conf

```
devMode=true
myLegalName="O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"
p2pAddress="IP_address_of_machineB:10008"
rpcSettings {
    address="localhost:10009"
    adminAddress="localhost:10010"
}
security {
    authService {
        dataSource {
            type=INMEMORY
            users=[
                {
                    password=test
                    permissions=[
                        ALL
                    ]
                    user=user1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I see the following error in the node logs:

```
[ERROR] 15:18:45+0800 [Node thread-1] corda.flow.processEventsUntilFlowIsResumed - Flow interrupted while waiting for events, aborting immediately {actor_id=internalShell, actor_owning_identity=O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, fiber-id=10000003, flow-id=86f29b02-f5d2-4eac-9803-1de797cb43b3, invocation_id=e3c19de7-1052-412f-bc2a-05c1014f7fc3, invocation_timestamp=2019-05-21T06:57:58.807Z, origin=internalShell, session_id=7639f617-f126-4e0c-b4d1-5515f62a85cd, session_timestamp=2019-05-21T06:56:57.730Z, thread-id=181}
```

Comment: can you try to change localhost to machine ip

Comment: As mentioned by Akkapong, you have to specify the ipAddress of each of the machines. Also, your machine should open those those ports for access over the local network assuming all the nodes are running under the same local network.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following in the node.conf for both nodes:

```html
rpcSettings {
    address="0.0.0.0:10001"
    adminAddress="0.0.0.0:10002"
}
```